# What Windows API function should I use to mark/unmark files/folders as protected operating system file?

Tags: windows, winapi, file, directory

What Windows API function should I use to mark/unmark files/folders as protected operating system file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [SetFileAttributes()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365535(VS.85).aspx) API with flags `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN | FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM`.

Comment: There is a registry entry called UseSystemForSystemFolders that might change the required attribute

Answer (score 3):

[PathMakeSystemFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773726%28VS.85%29.aspx)() is the documented way to mark a directory as a system folder